# Validate commit message for a GitHub rebase and merge

Tags: git, github, githooks, git-rebase

I am looking for a way to validate commit message via a pre-receive hook.

I am able to validate it for squash and merge commit however, it does not work for GitHub rebase and merge.

```
set -e

zero_commit='0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
msg_regex='<pattern_here>'
release_branches=( topic master )
exit_code=0

containsElement () {
  local e match="$1"
  shift
  for e; do [[ "$e" == "$match" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}


while read oldsha newsha refname; do
    short_current_branch="$(echo ${refname} | sed 's/refs\/heads\///g')"

    if containsElement "${short_current_branch}" "${release_branches[@]}"; then
        echo "${short_current_branch} is in ${release_branches[@]}"
    else
        echo "${short_current_branch} is not in ${release_branches[@]}"
        echo "Skipping execution"
        continue
    fi

    case ${oldsha},${newsha} in
        *,${NULL_SHA1}) # it's a delete
            any_deleted=true;;
        ${NULL_SHA1},*) # it's a create
            new_list="$new_list $newsha";;
        *,*) # it's an update
            new_list="$new_list $newsha";;
    esac
done


if [[ -z "$new_list" ]]
then
    exit ${exit_code}
fi

commit_msg=()


git rev-list ${new_list} --not --all |
while read sha1; do
    message=$( git log --max-count=1 --format=%B ${sha1} | head -1)
    if  ! echo "${message}" | grep -o "<regex_pattern>" ; then
        echo "ERROR:"
        echo "ERROR: Your push was rejected because commit: ${commit}"
        echo "ERROR: is missing radar link in first line of below commit message:"
        echo "ERROR: ${message}"
        echo "ERROR:"
        echo "ERROR: Please fix commit message and push again."
        echo "ERROR: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise- 
        server@2.21/github/committing- 
        changes-to-your-project/changing-a-commit-message"
        echo "ERROR"
        exit_code=1
    fi
done

exit ${exit_code}
```